# ls_init_learn_rate does not match learn rate at iteration step 0

Tags: google-bigquery

As indicated by the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-create#model_option_list) we've adjusted the `ls_init_learn_rate` to match the last doubled learning rate (12.8 in our case). However, the indicated learn rate in the training info at interation step 0 is 3.2.

[Training Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5W99Y.png)

The query for this specific model is the following, but we've tested the same behavior with other models as well.

```
#standardSQL
CREATE OR REPLACE MODEL `dataset.table` 
OPTIONS(model_type='logistic_reg', ls_init_learn_rate=12.8) AS
SELECT
  IF(totals.transactions IS NULL, 0, 1) AS label,
  device.operatingSystem AS os,
  device.isMobile AS is_mobile,
  geoNetwork.country AS country,
  totals.pageviews AS pageviews
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_*`
WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20160801' AND '20160901'
  AND MOD(ABS(FARM_FINGERPRINT(fullVisitorId)), 10) < 7
```

Is this behavior expected?